# What does e.body is null mean in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, null, firebug, jquery-1.6

I don't understand, FireBug started to show "**e.body is null**"

```
)}return this.pushStack(d,a,e.selector...a:a+"px")}}),a.jQuery=a.$=f})(window);
```

on line **18** from **jquery.min.js** using version **1.6.2**.

I don't remember what I did yesterday for this error to show up today. Any hint so I can know a little bit more where to search in my code?

It's appear before any ajax request and even before any console.log instruction I ave in my script, but still don't really know where's this error coming from.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you show a minimal script of your that still produces this error? hard to debug like this..

Comment: You shouldn't be debugging with the minified file.  Variable names are shortened to reduce size and lose their meaning.  There is also no reference to e.body in the code you provided.

Comment: Indeed. Use the full file `jquery.js`. Make a copy of your HTML/JS code which is using jQuery. Then cut it down as much as possible as long as you still get the same error by removing unrelated and irrelevant HTML/JS code lines step by step. At the point the error disappears, go a step back and provide that cutdown code in your question, so that we can just copy'n'paste'n'run it ourselves to see the same problem.

Comment: @Nanne: Actually, my script make a couple of hundreds of lines :S

Comment: @BalusC & Dennis: Okay thanks, I've changed it to the full jQuery script, I'll try to cut my code to find it. Thanks!

Comment: @jeremy : the trick is to remove stuff that doesn't have anything to do with the error, until the error doesn't occur. Take one step back and then post. read http://sscce.org/ if needed...

Answer (score 0):

After changing jQuery.min to jQuery, I removed some part of my code and finally I found that:

```
var documentHeight = $(document).height();
```

It wasn't in the $(document).ready part of the script... Don't know why the error appear just today, but thanks for the hint, I'll remember it!